# How to Reduce the time delay for streaming RTSP uing player(WINDOWS)

Tags: vlc, rtsp, http-live-streaming, quicktime, realplayer

I have a rtsp address from ip camera and i want to display it in player like VLC, QuickTime or RealPlayer. the problem is when i tried to display it through the player, there are a few second time delay between the the player and the real video. Is there any specific setting to reduce the time delay?

Comment: Maybe a better question for the Super User site.

Answer (score 0):

try `vlc --network-caching 150 --clock-jitter 0 --clock-synchro 0  rtsp://your-ip-address:8554/mystream`